# Data not being transformed Node.js Transform streams

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, nodejs-stream, through2

I'm trying to make a transform stream flow that is taking data from `socket.io`, converting it to JSON, and then sending it to stdout. I am totally perplexed as to why data just seems to go right through without any transformation. I'm using the `through2` library. Here is my code:

```
getStreamNames().then(streamNames => {
        const socket = io(SOCKETIO_URL);
        socket.on('connect', () => {
            socket.emit('Subscribe', {subs: streamNames});
        });

        const stream = through2.obj(function (chunk, enc, callback) {
            callback(null, parseString(chunk))
        }).pipe(through2.obj(function (chunk, enc, callback) {
            callback(null, JSON.stringify(chunk));
        })).pipe(process.stdout);

        socket.on('m', data => stream.write(data));

    },
);
```

`getStreamNames` returns a promise which resolves to an array of stream names (i'm calling an external `socket.io` API) and `parseString` takes a string returned from the API and converts it to JSON so it's manageable.

What I'm looking for is my console to print out the stringify'd JSON after I parse it using `parseString` and then make it stdout-able with `JSON.stringify`. What is actually happening is the data is going right through the stream and doing no transformation.

For reference, the data coming from the API is in a weird format, something like

`field1~field2~0x23~fieldn`

and so that's why I need the `parseString` method.

I must be missing something. Any ideas?

EDIT:

parseString:

```
function(value) {
    var valuesArray = value.split("~");
    var valuesArrayLenght = valuesArray.length;
    var mask = valuesArray[valuesArrayLenght - 1];
    var maskInt = parseInt(mask, 16);
    var unpackedCurrent = {};
    var currentField = 0;
    for (var property in this.FIELDS) {
        if (this.FIELDS[property] === 0) {
            unpackedCurrent[property] = valuesArray[currentField];
            currentField++;
        }
        else if (maskInt & this.FIELDS[property]) {
            if (property === 'LASTMARKET') {
                unpackedCurrent[property] = valuesArray[currentField];
            }
            else {
                unpackedCurrent[property] = parseFloat(valuesArray[currentField]);
            }
            currentField++;
        }
    }

    return unpackedCurrent;
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show `parseString` method please?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the stream you're writing, is actually `process.stdout`, because `.pipe` returns the last `stream.Writable`, so you can keep chaining, in your case, `process.stdout`.

```
const x = stream.pipe(stream2).pipe(stream3).pipe(process.stdout);
x === process.stdout // true
```

So all you were doing was: `process.stdout.write(data)` without going through the pipeline.

What you need to do, is assign your first `through2` stream to the `stream` variable, and then `.pipe` on that stream.

```
const stream = through2.obj((chunk, enc, callback) => {
    callback(null, parseString(chunk))
});

stream
    .pipe(through2.obj((chunk, enc, callback) => {
        callback(null, JSON.stringify(chunk));
    }))
    .pipe(process.stdout);

socket.on('m', data => stream.write(data));
```

Comment: You sir are a lifesaver.

Comment: this answer was also extremely helpful for me too, asked here and self-answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68835344/add-transform-before-write-stream/69724619#69724619